# Why do browsers don't accept relative path to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, relative-path, absolute-path

I put a relative path to the javascript file before the closing body tag in HTML-document, but it didn't work out. All the browsers, where I did open a console returned an error, that file can't be found. When I used an absolute path to the javascript file - it worked, but I know it's wrong to do so.

That's a relative path I firstly tried, but it failed:

```
javascript/vsjs.js
```

And here is an absolute path, that did work out

```
E:\programming\test\javascript\vsjs.js
```

Can anyone explain why browsers don't accept relative path?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code so we can see the issue, browsers do accept relative path

Comment: Can you let me know how you used relative path exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the file that includes the js file? If in "test" folder, then use relative path like

```
<script src="/javascript/vsjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Apologies for such late respond. Problem solved, but thank you, sir, for trying to help me.